# Transposing variables

Tags: stata

Is there an easy way to transpose my variables in Stata?

From:

```
-.48685038  -.13912173  -.91550094  -.96246505
-1.4760038   1.2873173  -.22300169   .25329232
-.01091149  -.58777297   .49454963   2.2842488
-.01376025  -.03060045  -.26231077   .32238093
.51557881  -2.1968436   .36612388  -.40590465
```

To:

```
-.48685038  -1.4760038  -.01091149  -.01376025   .51557881
-.13912173   1.2873173  -.58777297  -.03060045  -2.1968436
-.91550094  -.22300169   .49454963  -.26231077   .36612388
-.96246505   .25329232   2.2842488   .32238093  -.40590465
```

My understanding is that I have to create a matrix first:

```
mkmat *, matrix(data)
matrix data = data'
svmat data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `xpose`:

```
. webuse xposexmpl, clear

. list

     +--------------------------------+
     | county   year1   year2   year3 |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |      1    57.2    11.3    19.5 |
  2. |      2    12.5     8.2    28.9 |
  3. |      3      18    14.2    33.2 |
     +--------------------------------+

. xpose, clear varname

. list

     +-------------------------------+
     |   v1     v2     v3   _varname |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |    1      2      3     county |
  2. | 57.2   12.5     18      year1 |
  3. | 11.3    8.2   14.2      year2 |
  4. | 19.5   28.9   33.2      year3 |
     +-------------------------------+
```